# Difference between CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE and CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_MEMORY in Linux kernel config

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, memory

This [page](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RANDOMIZE_BASE.html) says that `RANDOMIZE_BASE` is for KASLR and it randomizes the physical AND virtual addresses which is obvious in 32-bit and comprehensible in 64-bit.

But what does `RANDOMIZE_MEMORY` do exactly? This [page](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RANDOMIZE_MEMORY.html) says:

> Randomizes the base virtual address of kernel memory sections (physical memory mapping, vmalloc & vmemmap).

What does this mean? Does this mean, that the different sections are split somehow and located not together but with some space in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RANDOMIZE_BASE` is a feature available on most architectures which [randomises the virtual and physical base address of the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/security/self-protection.html#text-and-module-base).

`RANDOMIZE_MEMORY` is an x86-64-specific feature which *additionally* [randomises the offsets of `page_offset_base`, `vmalloc_base`, `vmemmap_base`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt), *i.e.* the locations of the physical mapping in kernel memory, the `vmalloc` space, and the virtual memory map. As you can see from the linked memory map, all of these are followed by holes which allows them to be moved around without having to deal with overlap with whatever comes before or after them in memory.